# datatable header sort icon position

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

i have been trying to add datatable. Icons are not positioning correctly.
i have added below scripts

this is how it looks

[image]

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: `javascript` files should come after `css` files

Comment: @IamRaviteja, how is that related to the question? It does not make any difference for how the icons is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just needs below css.

```
 <link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You include three different CSS files for default style, Bootstrap and jQuery UI. You should pick the one that you will use and remove the others.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap):

> For CSS only a single file should be included as the styling library will provide the core styling options for the table. The CSS files have the format `dataTables.{style}.css` (`dataTables.bootstrap.css` for Bootstrap for example).